# A mysterious cipher on Reddit

Tags: cipher

First of all I must specify that the cipher is not mine - I found it in a post on Reddit by a user named master with a few numbers after it. I'll give you some context...

I have always been into cryptography and to learn I started following some people on Reddit (I know I sound like a stalker). Following a certain user (u/jacobb11) I discovered a page on Reddit with a series of ciphers that he and other users were trying to crack. I didn't understand much about it, but the other users had solved several parts. The page talked about an experiment that put together a number of users to crack a code or something.

A few days ago almost all the posts on the page were deleted except this one. I don't understand much about it, but if there's anyone here who is good with these things I'd be really curious to know what it says.
For anyone interested the reddit page is r/themastercode.

[image: Codes page 1]

[image: Codes page 2]

[image: Codes page 3]

Here is the text version.
1). 20-8-9-19-13-1-10-5-19-20-9-3-14-21-13-2-5-18-9-19-20-8-5-15-14-12-25-15-14-5-20-8-1-20-2-18-9-14-7-
19-20-18-21-5-12-21-3-11-19-1-4-12-25-6-15-18-25-15-21-12-21-3-11-9-19-21-19-5-12-5-19-19-1-7-1-9-14-
19-20-13-5.

2). 1101000110.

3). 0-24-12-3-14-0-5-66-3-1-7-1-1-1-99-10-4-1-7-23-22-2-1-2-3-8-65-1-90-3-16-24-5-89-0-5-67-14-3-6-8-13-9-
54-33-8-12-21-30.

A). 15-23-23-12-18-23-10-27-23-14-9-26-10-29-28-15-23-12-22-13-13-12-13-12-21-29-11-16-21-23-26-13-28-
17-21-13-28-23-11-26-13-9-28-13-28-16-13-31-23-26-20-12-9-22-12-17-9-21-18-29-27-28-15-13-28-28-17-
22-15-27-28-9-26-28-13-12.

4). 0-9-2-4-14-0-21-45-7-75-32-2-1-15-1-1-3-20-99-9-6-7-80-1-5-19-1-3-67-18-5-19-0-23-1.

5). 17-9-0-24-15-6-26-21-16-24-11-3-22-9-0-10-1-18-21-9-1-21-11-4-7-9-18-6-20-19-22-12-15.

6). 9-6-1-0-12-2-1-24-16-2-17-5-15-20-6-7-0-11-6-12-7-5-21-17-8-10-0-6-16.

B). 230-322-391-437-138-460-460-230-529-138-69-506-483-598-368-506-460-207-368-506-299-115-437-138-
46-299-299-598-460-207-46-437-391-138-345-46-299-299-598-368-506-437-460-138-345-460-138-460-
483-207-230-345-184-460-46-437-138-46-69-368-506-483-483-368-184-138-483-460-138-437-230-368-
506-460.

7). A-8-C-12-24-15-G-M-F-J-P-5-23-26-0-26-I-9-U-25-P-4-22-H-T-B.

8). 1860-110-110-450-15-104-88-540-86-99-1147-1980-13-95-1000-1350-283-104-86-450.

C). 30-13-6-28-10-2-22-18-6-19-24-21-18-10-19-15.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide the text as text, instead of screenshots?

Comment: Partial answer: 1) is rot13(N bar M gjragl fvk: Guvf znwrfgvp ahzore vf gur bayl bar gung oevatf gehr yhpx. Fnqyl sbe lbh, yhpx vf hfryrff ntnvafg zr.)

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

> 1). 20-8-9-19-13-1-10-5-19-20-9-3-14-21-13-2-5-18-9-19-20-8-5-15-14-12-25-15-14-5-20-8-1-20-2-18-9-14-7- 19-20-18-21-5-12-21-3-11-19-1-4-12-25-6-15-18-25-15-21-12-21-3-11-9-19-21-19-5-12-5-19-19-1-7-1-9-14- 19-20-13-5.

How I solved it:

> Using a basic A1Z26 cipher decoder, I was able to get this:
>  thismajesticnumberistheonlyonethatbringstruelucksadlyforyouluckisuselessagainstme
>  A.K.A:
>  This majestic number is the only one that brings true luck. Sadly for you, luck is useless against me.

This was pretty basic, and set a good foundation for the next one I was able to solve.

> A). 15-23-23-12-18-23-10-27-23-14-9-26-10-29-28-15-23-12-22-13-13-12-13-12-21-29-11-16-21-23-26-13-28- 17-21-13-28-23-11-26-13-9-28-13-28-16-13-31-23-26-20-12-9-22-12-17-9-21-18-29-27-28-15-13-28-28-17- 22-15-27-28-9-26-28-13-12.

Here's what I did:

> Again, it seemed that these were numbers with a range of `24`, although some of the numbers were above `26`, making the code invalid. So I subtracted `1` from every number in the sequence, tried it, and repeated. Eventually, `7` seemed to be the magic number, and it translated to:
>  goodjobsofarbutgodneededmuchmoretimetocreatetheworldandiamjustgettingstarted
>  "Good job so far, but God needed much more time to create the world and I am just getting started."

That's as far as I've gotten, but hopefully that can help somebody else along :)